# How to iterate over each output of awk with sh?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a `test.sh` file which awks through a text file `test.bed`:

```
1   31  431
1   14  1234
1   54  134
2   435 314
2   314 414
```

with

```
while read line;do
    echo $line  
    # ... more code ... #
done < <(awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1 {print $0}' test.bed )
```

Running this with `bash test.sh` works, but with `sh test.sh` it gives syntax errors. How could I do the above using `sh` instead of `bash`?

---

The error that it gives is

```
test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 5: `done < <(awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1 {print $0}' test.bed )'
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @vidit test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 5: `done < <(awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1 {print $0}' test.bed )'

Comment: which env you're using? I didn't experienced this kind of error. Could you please paste your complete script?

Comment: `<( ... )` is not valid syntax for `sh` (or `bash` in `sh` compatibility mode).

Comment: Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and you'll probably rethink your design.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) is a `bash` extension - not specified by `POSIX`. This is `sh` compatible..

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1 {print $0}' test.bed  | while read line; do
echo $line
    # ... more code ... #
done
```

Comment: That is riddled with bugs which will bite you given various combinations of contents of test.bed, the directory you run the tool from, environment settings, etc. It also has redundant awk code but that's less important. **IF** a shell loop like this were necessary then the way to write it would be `awk -F '\t' '$1 == 1' test.bed  | while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$line";
done`. Use `printf` instead of `echo` if your shell supports it for additional robustness.

Comment: No, I said the approach is wrong and even if the approach was right your answer would still be the wrong way to implement it. See my first comment.

Comment: The original script would work if it started with `#!/bin/bash`. I try to avoid bashisms, in scripts but there's no reason the original poster has to.